# Retrieving the all-numeric appId for an iOS app?

Tags: ios, app-id

I'm looking to get the 10-digit appId (all numeric) for my iOS app; when I go to the provisioning profile, I see appIds that are 10 characters, but include alphanumeric text.  I believe that there should also be an all-numeric appId (to use when sending users to the app store to rate an app, etc.) but am not clear on where or how to retrieve it.

Any help gratefully received.

Thanks.

-d